# svn commit fails: File not found: Transaction »52-1r«

Tags: svn

The minimal reproducible failure is as follows:

```
> mkdir test && cd test
> svn co https://svn.server.com/repo .
> vim php/main.php
> svn commit
Sending        php/main.php
Transmitting file data ..svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File not found: Transaction »52-1r«, Path »/php/main.php«
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
```

What puzzles me is that this is a clean checkout, nobody has touched the repo (an `svn update` before the commit makes no difference) and the file does exist (I can `ls` it or `vim` it).

The only notable thing here is that the folder name which contains main.php has changed between r1 and r52.

Where does that issue come from, why can that file not be found when it's obviously there?  And how can I fix this?

Comment: try `svn cleanup` and then do a commit. If that doesn't help, you'll have to get onto the server and do `svnadmin lslocks` and `svnadmin lstxns`. You might have to use `svnadmin rmlocks` and `svnadmin rmtxns` to clean up.

Comment: @DavidW. The `svn cleanup` didn't fix the commit.  And both `svnadmin lslocks` and `svnadmin lstxns` return nothing.

Comment: Okay, take a look at the repository, and make sure the permissions of all the files and directories are owned by the user who is running the server (or Apache if you're using Apache), and are writable by that user. I sometimes find that bad permissions will allow a checkout, but not a commit.

Comment: @DavidW. Wow, I found the issue... see the answer below :)  Thanks for the tips though!

Comment: I had a very similar problem. We had started the svn server using the wrong path.

Comment: transaction is out of date,back up your program ,update ,and commit your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer**

My client version of subversion was outdated.

**Long Answer**

I'm running [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) on my Mac and somehow assumed that I had [Subversion](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=subversion) installed as a part of that.  Alas, I had not, and my `svn` command was Apple's default `svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)` which runs with subversion format 10.

The repository runs `svn, version 1.7.13 (r1516569)` which runs with subversion format 12.

After updating (i.e. installing) my local `svn, version 1.8.3 (r1516576)` which runs with format 12 as well and `svn upgrade` my local repository tree to the current version, I could commit all my changes without problems.

Answer (score 42):

You will also get this message when creating a tag using the client by copying into a new path where more than one level of the desired folder structure does not exist in repository. (Jeez that sounds complicated.)

In other words, I attempted to create a tag:

/projects/MyAwesomeProject/tags/myFirstTag

...but the 'tags' folder did not exist yet. I expected the client to do the work for me; manually creating the 'tags' folder was the cure.

Comment: It sounds like a better error message would have been beneficial :)

Comment: Thanks, have just encountered exactly this issue. Amusingly (or otherwise) it also fails if the directory already exists because you've just created the full path for it - I suppose I can probably see the logic for this one though.

Comment: `svn mkdir` to manually make the directory, or re-run with the `--parents` argument like so: `svn copy --parents source destination -m "Message"`.

Comment: Similar to my experience. it seems you cannot create a tag two levels down. I had this problem, doing so. Example: Tag->ChildFolder->SnapshotFolder  Removing ChildFolder fixed my issue. It will however create the SnapshotFolder for me if it doesn't already exist and complain if it does.

Answer (score 9):

This is resolved for me after selecting check box present at bottom of SVN client. "Create intermediate folders"

Answer (score 3):

`svn cleanup` did the trick for me