# Tortoise SVN commit error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I've looked up previous posts for this issue I have but they are quite old now and none of the solutions have worked for this particular file I am having issues with.

Before I go any further, please be aware that I am not an expert at SVN, in fact we do not I believe fully utilise this at my company and only have a working knowledge of it for committing changes to code configurations. Not myself, nor any of my colleagues in this office know the ins and outs of how SVN works.

I'm trying to commit a small change to a script in my SVN repository, but am getting this error.

[image: SVN Commit Error]

I had this problem with another file earlier, and to fix this I did the following:

1. Revert the folder
2. SVN Cleanup
3. Unversion and add the file to the ignore list
4. Commit the folder
5. Replace file with a new verison of the file
6. Add
7. Commit folder.

However, for this particular file, this hasn't worked and it doesn't seem to matter what I try I just cannot get this fixed.

If I delete the entire folder manually (through Windows, not SVN delete).  Then do an SVN Update, I get the folder back with the files, including the problem file.  This suggests to me the file is the current "live" file from the repository.  But I still can't make changes and commit, and the above solution I used for the other problem file I had earlier also doesn't work.

Is there anything else I can try?

Many thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: Bit of a guess, but does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18835625/1698557) apply to your situation?

Comment: Can you try with a brand new checkout (and then add and commit the file)? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the replies.

@Jon - this solution worked.  I did a SVN Checkout to a new directory and it appears to work ok now. Hopefully I haen't spoken too soon :)

Thanks

Steve